# Any known way to hide Sitecore sensitive data

Tags: security, role-management

We have configured Sitecore security on items for the roles and seeing the sensitive data in the browser logs. We have a custom error page which interrogates the return codes(403/404/ or any other) and redirect to an item.
For Ex: 
Assume two roles : Admin and customer. 

If there are two items:

Item1 - Admin and Customer have read access
Item2 - Only Admin has access

When customer tries to access Item2 then Sitecore is redirecting to 403 as expected and the browser url is https://mywebsite.com/error.aspx?code=403. However when I see the browser network tab I see this : https://mywebsite.com/error.aspx?code=403&**item**=2fitemname&**user**=username&**site**=sitename

Is there any way to hide the highlighted information(item/user/site)?

Comment: can you try using `<setting name="RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect" value="true"/>` and see if that fixes your issue? I don't have a Sitecore running now to check if it works

Comment: @adb : Thanks for getting back. I tried the above setting and it completely turns off Sitecore routing. I still want to use Sitecore redirect mechanism except I want to find a way to exclude all the additional parameters(like user, site) that Sitecore is adding.

Comment: Then probably you have to override the default sitecore logic for redirrects. Check this blog post: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/handling-errors-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Answer (score 6):

I was able to find the processor(`Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest` in `Sitecore.Kernel`) which adds these query strings and they are not configurable. To fix the issue I created a new class(`CustomExecureRequest`) and copied the processor and removed the query strings from `HandleSiteAccessDenied`, `HandleItemNotFound` and other methods. 
I then created a patch xml file inside include folder similar to below:

```
 <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
    <httpRequestBegin>
    <processor patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="YOUR CUSTOM CLASS TYPE, YOUR ASSEMBLY NAME" />
    </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
```

Hope this helps some one!